# Is Schiff Move Free products is Halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Schiff Move Free products include Chondroitin sulfate which mentioned on the pack that it derived from Porcine.
http://www.movefree.com/shop-products/advanced-plus-msm-vitamin-d3/move-free-advanced-plus-msm-vitamin-d-80-count#

Is Schiff Move Free is Halal or not?

Comment: Chondroitin sulfate can be derived from both cows etc. and pigs as well. I dont have pack of schiff move so if it is derived from pig then it is haram and if it is derived from halal source then it is halal.

Comment: Thanks for feedback....You can check the link above and will find in the lower right side an image for the pack ingredients..... Please check

Comment: Oh yeah that one!! My luck! I read the info several times and magnified the pack image many times but was unable to find what you have said. Now I found it on the image on the right side and they state that it is derived from povine(cattles) or porcine!! And definitely it becomes haram then.

Answer (score 1):

From walgreens website

https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/schiff-move-free-joint-health-glucosamine-chondroitin-plus-msm-%26-vitamin-d3-tablets/ID=prod3855572-product

" Chrondroitin Sulfate is derived from bovine and porcine sources."
porcine is from Pork

[image: capture from wlagreens]